# Add a margin to a row in CSS (at least that's what I think I'm trying to do?)

Tags: html, css

currently I am adding a icon "services" section to my website. I know next to no css which is why I am posting here. I want to have it so that the kind of "blocks" that the icons are sitting on dont go to the edge of the page and leave a margin similar in width to the margin the have from each other. I would appreciate help on this. Thanks very much. I have included a link to my JSFiddle, and would appreciate your answer in the form of an edited version of it, if that is not too much trouble.

http://jsfiddle.net/hqtzaycq/2/

```
<div class="row">
                <div id="about">
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                     <div class="about-div">
                     <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o fa-4x icon-round-border" ></i>
                   <h3 >Lorem ipsum</h3>
                 <hr />
                       <hr />
                   <p >
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                        Aenean commodo . 

                   </p>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-set"  >Lorem ipsum</a>
                </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4" data-scroll-reveal="enter from the bottom after 0.5s">
                     <div class="about-div">
                     <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-4x icon-round-border" ></i>
                   <h3 >Lorem ipsum</h3>
                 <hr />
                       <hr />
                   <p >
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                        Aenean commodo . 

                   </p>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-set"  >Lorem ipsum</a>
                </div>
                   </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4" data-scroll-reveal="enter from the bottom after 0.6s">
                     <div class="about-div">
                     <i class="fa fa-magic fa-4x icon-round-border" ></i>
                   <h3 >Lorem ipsum</h3>
                 <hr />
                       <hr />
                   <p >
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                        Aenean commodo . 

                   </p>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-set"  >Lorem ipsum</a>
                </div>
                   </div>

                 </div>
               </div>

.body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.about-div {
    padding: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.icon-round-border {
    border: 10px double #efefef;
    color: #2b2e2f;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

    .icon-round-border:hover {
        color: #efefef;
        border: 10px double #fff;
        background-color: #414546;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s;
        -o-transition: 0.3s;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

.about-div hr {
    border: 1px solid #2b2e2f;
}

.about-div h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.about-div p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn-set {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.about {
    Width: 90vw;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `margin-left` and/or `margin-right`?

Comment: You should use `container`.

Comment: @KeithAnderson Please elaborate your question. Thanks

Comment: How would I have elaborated on my question? and to takendarkk, I did but it didn't help, and Nenand Vracar how would I have implemented it? Please go in detail like the answer which helped me below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the row with a clearfix. That way you will reclaim the native margin and padding, instead of overwriting it.

Remove this:

```
<div class="row">
```

And add this instead

```
<div class="clearfix">
```

One of the biggest mistakes new front end developers do is to overwrite classes when the problem lies in using the correct classes first. :) It happens.

Your [**jfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hqtzaycq/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Works a charm. I'll have to remember this for next time!